# A "divide-and-conquer" iterative procedure for minimizing a sum of convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, newton-raphson

For simplicity, let's assume $f_i: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex and define

$$ g(x) := \sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x) $$

Suppose we want to compute

$$ x^* := \arg\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}} g(x) $$

The Newton-Raphson iterations take the following form

$$ x_{t+1} = x_t - \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f''_i(x_t)\right)^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f'_i(x_t)\right) $$

I was playing around and happened on the following idea. Suppose we solve
\begin{align*}
f_i'(x_i^*) = 0 \implies x_i^* = [f_i']^{-1}(0)
\end{align*}
Then, perform a Taylor series expansion for $f_i$ around $x_i^*$:
\begin{align*}
f_i(x) &\approx f_i(x_i^*) + f'_i(x_i^*)(x - x_i^*) + \frac{1}{2}f''_i(x_i^*)(x - x_i^*)^2 \\
&= f_i(x_i^*) + \frac{1}{2}f''_i(x_i^*)(x - x_i^*)^2
\end{align*}
And so
\begin{align*}
g(x) \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n}[f_i(x_i^*)  + \frac{1}{2}f''_i(x_i^*)(x - x_i^*)^2]
\end{align*}
and this approximation is minimized at

$$ \widetilde{x} = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}f''_i(x_i^*)x_i^*}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}f''_i(x_i^*)} $$

From this, I had the idea to define $x_0 = \widetilde{x}$ and continue iterations of this manner:

$$ x_{t+1} = \dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}f''_i(x_t)x_i^*}{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}f''_i(x_t)} $$

How does this procedure compare against Newton-Raphson?

Comment: Are you assuming that you know the minimum of each $f_i$?

Comment: Yes, $x_i^*$ is the minimum of each $f_i$.

Comment: First things first, do you know if $x^*$ is even a fixed point of your procedure, i.e. if $x_t=x^*$, is $x_{t+1}=x^*$ as well?